# Correct And Efficient Way to create 10 List in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

How to make 10 Lists in java such as each list has variable amount of data.

MySolution:

I used the follwoing approach to solve this issue.

```
  ArrayList a1=new ArrayList();
  ArrayList a2=new ArrayList();
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
     for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
     {
       a1.add(0);
     }
     a2.add(a1);
  }
```

But, this approach created only 1 list:
having the following elements when the user enters.

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: `List<List<PLEASE_USE_GENERICS>>` ?

Comment: Adding something to a list does not copy it. You need to create a new list `a1` on each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: And you don't need an "efficient" way, you need a *correct* way.

Comment: Your code does not create 10 lists, just 2, `a1` and `a2`, and then adds 50 times `0` into `a1`, and 5 times `a1` into `a2`. So the result is `a2` containing 5 references to `a1`, which contains 50 zeros.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes I need an Efficient and correct way.

Comment: @user6389648 what do you think you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: By Effiecient I mean Fast Retrieval,Generic Code and less Memory Utilization.

Comment: @user6389648 nah, you just need obviously-correct code; if you do it right, these rather nebulous goals follow.

Comment: @AndyTurner Okay Thankx.You know everything what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
List<List<Integer>> outer=new ArrayList<>();

  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
     List<Integer> inner=new ArrayList<Integer>();
     for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
     {
       inner.add(0);
     }
     outer.add(inner);
  }
```

For more examples please go through [the documentation of Java Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/TOC.html)

Comment: For the sake of clarity, I would use `outer` for `a1` and `inner` for `a2`.

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of raw types.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 stream API

```
List<List<Integer>> res = IntStream.range(0,5).boxed()
                            .map(p-> IntStream.generate(() -> 0)
                                        .limit(10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Note:** Using normal old fashional way is faster than this; because of the small data set we are dealing with.